# How to deal with empty white space Titanium

Tags: view, titanium-alloy

Take the following code snippet:

```
<View id='container'>
<View id='child' width=100 height=100/>
<View id='child1' width=100 height=100/>
<View id='child2' width=100 height=100 />
<View id='child3'width=100 height=100 visible='false' bottom='0'/>
</View>
```

I have a container and nested in it, child views.

Say I make child 3 visible false, the problem is the window will not resize accordingly and there will be white space for where child 3 is. As it is rendered, but hidden.

How can I deal with white space in titanium.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced this problem. I simply set `height` property to 0 instead of making `view` `invisible`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add that element later after the window is created using the js.Just change the code to add the view instead of making it visible.

something like this :

```
$.container.add(child3);
```

Hope it helps.